# Multiple Transforms for VSCode Snippet

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I've got a few snippets set up and working as I would like to, but I'm having a hard time getting one snippet to work where I believe I will need to have multiple transforms occur?

Essentially I have a TypeScript Interface defined for one of my components.

i.e. `IRadioButtonListProps.ts` which is inside of an `Interfaces` folder. The `Interfaces` folder has a sibling folder named `Theme` containing an interface named `IRadioButtonListTheme.ts`

Inside of `IRadioButtonListProps` I'm trying to stub out the entire interface. The snippet I currently have stubs out the interface like...

```
import * as React from 'react';
import IRadioButtonListPropsTheme from '../Theme/IRadioButtonListPropsTheme';

export interface IRadioButtonListPropsProps {
    ...props...
}

export default IRadioButtonListPropsProps;
```

The import line inside of the snippet is...

```
"import I${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)\\..+$/$1/}Props from './Interfaces/I${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)\\..+$/$1/}Props';"
```

What I'm trying to have happen and can't seem to figure out is how to also remove the word "Props". So instead of `import IRadioButtonListPropsTheme...` I would get import `import IRadioButtonListTheme...`.

At the same time, I want to remove all extensions, including those of the form *.abc.abc ("two" extensions) and *.abc (one simple extension).

Is this possible?

Comment: What is `(.*)\\..+$` supposed to match?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variable-transforms

This removes the extension from the file name if there is one.

Comment: Try changing `(.*)\\..+$` to `(.*?)(?:Props)?\\.[^.]+$`

Comment: That didn't break like what I was attempting, but it also didn't change the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't crystal clear what you what but try:

```
"import ${TM_FILENAME/((\\w*)Props)*?(\\..*)/$2/}Theme from './Interfaces/${TM_FILENAME/((\\w*)Props)*?(\\..*)/$2/}Theme';"
```

which results in:

```
import IRadioButtonListTheme from './Interfaces/IRadioButtonListTheme';
```

from `IRadioButtonListProps.ts`
and

```
import CheckboxListTheme from './Interfaces/CheckboxListTheme';
```

from `CheckboxListProps.test.tsx`

[**Edit**]  Here is a simpler version which I think also works:

```
 "import ${TM_FILENAME/(Props)*?(\\..*)//}Theme from './Interfaces/${TM_FILENAME/(Props)*?(\\..*)//}Theme';"
```

1. match any "Props", if any, replace with nothing.
2. match from first \. to end of filename, replace with nothing.

Comment: This did remove the word `Props`, but stopped ensuring that there wasn't an extension. Some of the snippets are used on test files named similar to `CheckboxList.test.tsx`. I was using the `TM_FILENAME_BASE` to remove the `.tsx` and then the existing transform to remove `.test`

Comment: So one of your intentions is to remove anything after and including the first . (dot)?  What should running the snippet on CheckboxList.test.tsx produce for the import statement?

Comment: `CheckboxList.test.tsx` and `CheckboxListProps.test.tsx` should both produce `CheckboxList` (as far as the transform is concerned).

Comment: I edited the answer above to address your multiple extension cae scenarios as well.

Comment: Any chance you could include a transform to grab the last directory in a path produced by `TM_DIRECTORY`? i.e. `c:\a\b\c\d\e` would produce `e`

Comment: Yes, but in the spirit of SO, you should post that as a new question.

Comment: done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52877815/vscode-snippet-transform-to-determine-the-containing-directory