# VSCode snippet transform to determine the containing directory

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, transform

I've been unable to determine the transform to use to grab the directory that a new file is in from the `TM_DIRECTORY` that VSCode exposes?

i.e. For a path like `c:\a\b\c\d\e` I would like to get `e` as the output. I also have linux co-works so it should also work for something like `/mnt/a/b/c/d/e`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```
"stripLastDirectory": {
    "prefix": "lsd",
    "body": [
      "${TM_DIRECTORY/.*[\\\\|\\/]+(.*)/$1/}"
    ],
},
```

I am unable to test that on Linux but it should work on all OS's.